# Página não carrega no tamanho da tela

Tags: android, adobe-air, actionscript

Quero alterar o código para abrir no tamanho da tela. Estou usando:

```
 import flash.geom.Rectangle;
 import flash.media.StageWebView;
 var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
 webView.stage = this.stage;
_stageWebView.viewPort =  new Rectangle(0,0,stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
webView.loadURL("http://example.com");
```

Comment: Olá Rose, a resposta lhe ajudou, sobrou alguma duvida em relação a ela?

Answer (score 0):

Essa variavel parece errada `_stageWebView`, você não deveria setar no webview?

Assim:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;

var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort =  new Rectangle(0,0,stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
webView.loadURL("http://example.com");
```

Se ainda não funcionar tente:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;

var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
webView.loadURL("http://example.com");
```

E se ainda parecer que não funciona verifique se o site que está acessando usa esta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Se não usar pode ser "impressão sua" que "não esta funcionando", pode ser apenas o ajuste do zoom.